# UTF-8 encoding in request xml for soap request in linux

Tags: java, xml, linux, soap, jaxb

I am facing a strange issue. I have a soap service to store user data, for that I am calling a service and pass an XML document. The problem is that when I try from Windows, the `XML` is correctly shown with all valid `UTF-8` characters

But my server is a linux server and when it tries, the generated XML from the object has some garbage/junk characters for special `UTF-8` characters.

I use `JAXB` for XML conversion.

Here is the code that I use from Object to String

```
    String result = null;
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = ContextFactoryManager.getInstance().createJAXBContext(SomeObject.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, JAXBUtils.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT);jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, JAXBUtils.JAXB_FRAGMENT);
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, JAXBUtils.UTF8);
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(inputObject, writer);
    result = writer.toString();
```

When I run this code from my local server (from Windows) it works just fine, but when this code runs on server (from Linux), it converts special characters (like ö) to some junk character.

Please let me know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

finally I found the cause. It was no where related to the operating system. On server, a tomcat level `Valve` was configured. This valve was reading a request parameter (from `CatalinaRequest`).

When this URL was followed, https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.html#setCharacterEncoding%28java.lang.String%29

I found that the character encoding must be set prior to get any parameter.